How to Align Section Header with List Items in SwiftUI on iOS 18.2?
I am trying to align the section header with the start of the list item rows in SwiftUI (tested on iOS 18.2). However, the header does not align properly with the list items.
Here is my code:
    List {
        Section {
            Text("Row")
            Text("Row")
            Text("Row")
        } header: {
            Text("Header")
        }
        .headerProminence(.increased)
    }

I also tried wrapping the header in a VStack to set an alignment explicitly:
    List {
        Section {
            Text("Row")
            Text("Row")
            Text("Row")
        } header: {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Header")
            }
        }
        .headerProminence(.increased)
    }

Despite these attempts, the header is still not aligning with the rows.
Here's image of the issue.
Does anyone have suggestions or workarounds to fix this alignment issue?
